# ExtJS 4 adding CSS property to an action column

Tags: css, extjs

I use active column to generate dynaicly icons like this:

```
{xtype:'actioncolumn',
            width:25,
            align: 'center',
            items: [{
                icon: g_settings.iconUrl + 'view-icon.png' ,
                tdCls : 'someClass',
                handler: function() 
                {
                    alert('HI');
                }]
```

now to add the property which I want (in this case cursor:pointer) in ExtJS forum is written to add

```
.someClass
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

But I'm not sure where this should be written.

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in your CSS file that you have included on your page (you have a CSS file, right?).

For example like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
```

And then put the style definitions you want in the `styles.css` file. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Well, this is a solution but I was wondering if there isn't a way to add this where I define the action column itself, and not directly into the main CSS file?

Comment: Anyways this do the work. Thanks. If the other option is available please post the solution here.

Comment: In my opinion it is cleaner solution anyway to separate the style definitions. But regardless, defining styles within the icon definition does not seem to be supported - see [ExtJS documentation on ActionColumn](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-items) for reference.

Comment: Agreed. You should least use inline css.